# Route Specific Traffic From Default Gateway across VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, hamachi

OK, So here is the idea. I have a computer that runs on a separate internet connection than the one I am currently using. This computer hosts a PLEX server, and I would like to use it to host a Minecraft server as well. The problem with this internet connection is that the ISP (Metronet) uses double NAT-ing. This is being circumvented for the PLEX server using Hamachi, which can also be done for the Minecraft server as well, but it is obviously very inconvenient for everyone. I would like to instead route that specific traffic across my computer through the hamachi connection if that is possible.

I have tried setting up new routes in my routing table, but of course, may have been doing it wrong, and that may not even work anyways. but I would like for someone to be able to type in the public IP of my computer here, and for this computer to push that traffic across the hamachi connection for specific ports (25565, and the PLEX port which I forget.) if this is at all possible.